# Who is the god Latavya worshiped by Madhwas?

Tags: vaishnavism, dvaita, madhvacharya, madhwa

Madhvacharya’s philosophy or Dvaita divides Jivatmas or individual souls into three categories: Mukti Yogyas or those destined to attain Moksha, Nitya Samsaris or those destined to remain in Samsara forever, and Tamo Yogyas or those destined to go to Andhatamas, a place of eternal punishment.  Mukti Yogyas are further divided into many subcategories, the topmost of which is the Devas.  And then Devas are ranked in a Taratamya or gradation, which dictates which Devas will be reborn as which.  For instance the current Shiva is reborn as the next Adiseshan, and the current Adiseshan gets reborn as the next Garuda.

But at the top of this Taratamya is a list of 200 gods, known as the Ruju Ganas.  You can see a list of the top 100 out of the 200 [here](http://www.sripurandaraashrama.org/dasasahitya/articles/Taratamya.pdf).  Of these the top three names are Brahma, Vayu, and Latavya.  The current Latavya becomes the next Vayu, the current Vayu becomes the next Brahma, and the current Brahma attains Moksha.  But my question is, who is Latavya?

All I know about him is that Madhwas believe that the 15th century Madhwa philosopher Vadiraja Tirtha was an incarnation of Latavya.  But do either Madhwa works or Hindu scriptures provide any further information about him?  Like what is his story, and what is his function in the Universe?

Comment: First we need to understand riju gana, they are eligible for brahma post one by one is assigned one after other after brahmas time is over its a revolving post.. they are higher in place because they can become Brahma in one of the lifes. Currently we have brahma who is adhipati of  chitta, budhhi and manas in pinda andha, and brahmanda is adhipathi of garuda, sesha, Rudra. they will be doing tapas until there time. that is why they were higher in order

Comment: Vadiraja swamigal is incarnation of a Brahmana who is messager of Rukimi devi, he who brought the message from Rukmini devi to Krishna. In effect this indication of action Hanuman, so was the messager of Sita to Rama. he was riju gana. he will become next Vayu, after which he will become next brahma

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing this. Not sure this answer suffice your question.

Evidence in Skanda purana with name VadiRaja

[image: Evidence in Skanda purana with name VadiRaja]

There are some good sources that quotes lot of praManas about Sri Vadiraja.

http://www.sripurandaraashrama.org/dasasahitya/articles/SriVadirajaTheerthanamRujutwePramanaVachanani.pdf?fbclid=IwAR0GnBhd-2_fwmxHAd4sguGO9wxh2lTRQ4d8P4Hel_nUMuf96ZXqOMvdf74

Comment: Hi Arun! Although your answer says that The current Latavya becomes the next Vayu, the current Vayu becomes the next Brahma, and the current Brahma attains Moksha, but this is already stated by OP in the question. You are just repeating it. The main question of OP is **who is Latavya God.** and requires the description of that God and not the references for it. Besides this is English language site and the OP can't read  Sanskrit shlokas in Devanagari script. Also, try to add some description and explanation in the answer as link-only answers are not encouraged on the site.